# How to exclude a field from the SOLR search index for a specific content type

Tags: search, 9

I would like to exclude all body fields from the search index for a specific content type.

Reason: We have an Author content type with a bio in the Body field. However, for searches, we only want the author name to be indexed. We want the body field indexed for all other content.

Comment: Unfortunately the UI doesn't provide for that. You'll prob just need to overwrite the [`extractFields`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/search_api/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Utility/FieldsHelper.php#L105) method and add a conditional.